# Optimization issues with 2D sandbox terrain generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, lag, terrain

My game:

[image]

Each block has a class that doesn't run anything on update, and there is a 200 x 10 span of blocks. I'm implementing random terrain generation later, and this is what I want to be done.

BLOCK CODE: (in every single block, should I optimize? or do it differently?)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class scr_blockMechanics : MonoBehaviour {
//#EDITABLE VARS
    public string block_blockType;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    public bool isMineable { get; set; }
    public bool isRandomlyGenerated { get; set; }
    public bool isWall { get; set; }
//#STATIC VARS
    GameObject obj_blockItem;
//#START
    void Start () {
        obj_blockItem = GameObject.Find("main_blockItem");
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        if(isRandomlyGenerated == false){
            isMineable = false;
        }
//#CREATING WALLS
        /*if(isRandomlyGenerated == true && isWall == false){
            //#TODO Create walls!
            GameObject obj_blockWall = (GameObject)Instantiate(gameObject, transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            obj_blockWall.name = obj_blockWall.name + " WALL";
            obj_blockWall.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(
                obj_blockWall.transform.localPosition.x,
                obj_blockWall.transform.localPosition.y,
                5);


            Collider2D obj_blockWall_collider = obj_blockWall.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
            obj_blockWall_collider.enabled = false;

            Color obj_blockWall_color = Color.grey;//new Vector4(64, 64, 64, 1);

            SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer_wall = obj_blockWall.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            spriteRenderer_wall.color = obj_blockWall_color;

            scr_blockMechanics blockMechanics_wall = obj_blockWall.GetComponent<scr_blockMechanics>();
            blockMechanics_wall.isRandomlyGenerated = true;
            blockMechanics_wall.isMineable = false; //#TODO: not yet mineable, because it's a wall.
            blockMechanics_wall.isWall = true;

            obj_blockWall.name = blockMechanics_wall.block_blockType+" WALL";
        }*/
    }
//#CREATE ITEM
    void createItem(int uid){
        GameObject obj_blockItemNew = (GameObject)Instantiate(obj_blockItem, transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        obj_blockItemNew.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
        obj_blockItemNew.name = gameObject.name + " ITEM";
    }
//#DESTROY BLOCK
    void destroyBlock(){
        //print ("'"+transform.name+"' has been destroyed!");
        //spriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
        createItem(0);
        Destroy(transform.gameObject);
    }
//#UPDATE
    void Update () {
        if(renderer.IsVisibleFrom(Camera.main) == true){
            renderer.enabled = true;//gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        if(renderer.IsVisibleFrom(Camera.main) == false){
            renderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

'RANDOM' TERRAIN GENERATION

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class scr_randomGen : MonoBehaviour {


    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private string[] block_blockTypes = new string[]{
        "DIRT",        //#UID 0
        "STONE",       //#UID 1
        "STONE_BRICK", //#UID 2
    };

    void GENERATE(){
        //#DEFAULTS
        GameObject obj_block = GameObject.Find("main_block");
        int pos_startingPosX = -100;
        int pos_endingPosX = 100;

        int pos_startingPosY = 0;
        int pos_endingPosY = 10;

        float X = 0;
        float Y = 0;
        //#TERRAIN GENERATION
        for(X=pos_startingPosX;X<pos_endingPosX;X=X+1){
            GameObject obj_blockNew = (GameObject)Instantiate(obj_block, new Vector3(0 + (1*X),0,0), Quaternion.identity);
            scr_blockMechanics blockMechanics = obj_blockNew.GetComponent<scr_blockMechanics>();

            blockMechanics.isMineable = true;
            blockMechanics.isRandomlyGenerated = true;
            blockMechanics.block_blockType = block_blockTypes[2];

            obj_blockNew.name = blockMechanics.block_blockType+" "+X+", "+Y;

            for(Y=pos_startingPosY;Y<pos_endingPosY;Y=Y+1){
                obj_blockNew = (GameObject)Instantiate(obj_block, new Vector3(X,1 + (1*Y),0), Quaternion.identity);
                blockMechanics = obj_blockNew.GetComponent<scr_blockMechanics>();

                blockMechanics.isMineable = true;
                blockMechanics.isRandomlyGenerated = true;
                blockMechanics.block_blockType = block_blockTypes[2];

                obj_blockNew.name = blockMechanics.block_blockType+" "+X+", "+Y;
            }
        }
    }

    void Start () {
        GENERATE();
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I have it so that if the camera isn't looking at blocks it disables their sprite renderer so it's not rendering as much.

Should I just disable them as a whole? **I get 6fps upon running the game**.

When I only have, say, **10 - 20 blocks** instead of 2000 I get **130 FPS** (which is still low in my opinion)

What's the best way to optimize this? make it so I get atleast 70 fps? I wanted to use Java but I don't feel comfortable with the editor and I already put 2 hours of work into this.

I have looked at people's projects in Java and it's a lot smoother and they don't have to worry about the lag. And I have looked at peoples posts saying that it is possible to create a Terarria-like game in Unity but it's always going to be laggy.

Anybody got a good idea on how to fix the lag issues?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Unity but it seems like you are rendering all the screen objects every frame. Why don't you try waiting for interaction to update?

Comment: _"I get 130fps (which is still low in my opinion) "_ - considering that one requires a G-SYNC monitor (of which you can count on one hand) for 144 Hz, 130 FPS is quite good really (exorbitant frame-rates when VSYNC is off on non-G-SYNC monitors don't count).   2000 objects isn't alot however I wonder if you should not change `renderer.enabled` for every object for every frame if you know it hasn't changed since last frame.  Also, I would look into bounding boxes for the bricks and compare that to the view window rather than reverse projecting with the camera all the time

Comment: _"And I have looked at peoples posts saying that it is possible to create a **Terarria-like** game in Unity but it's **always going to be laggy**"_ - perhaps, but then again the game _[Broforce](https://unity3d.com/showcase/gallery/?platform=&genre=917&gametype=t-2d)_ looks like a reasonable implementation of 2D platformer with destructible environments and it was made with Unity 3D.

Comment: Okay, so I'll try @kailanjian 's suggestion with the waiting for an interaction to update.. although unity has it's own Update() function that gets put into each class automatically. But I'm sure I can make my own that when you click a block or something, it checks for an update.. but then there's the problem of character movement, and checking for an update every single frame so it can move smoothly. I have looked at some posts, and a suggestion is to make the world 1 mesh until interacted with.. just like how most voxel games do it.

Comment: Thank you @MickyDuncan for editing my post to make it more appealing. I will have a look at Broforce and I will look at Bounding Boxes. renderer.enabled actually gives it a boost in frames, but I do not think it is the best way to hide the objects when unseen. Perhaps games made in Java do not have this frame rate issue because they don't have to render the 3D boxes and and collision checks unless you implement it yourself. I do have Sprite Renderer that make them not have a 3D mesh. If you'd like to contact me on twitter @ iRaaptorDEV perhaps we can chat on direct messages if you'd like to.

Comment: Ah! I found out that, having a script in each and every block is what slowed it down. I have them disabled if they're not in the camera's view, and now I get 200+ FPS with thousands of blocks loaded. The only problem I am having now is that whenever you destroy a block, it slows the "Main Thread" down by 2ms. I will now figure out how to fix it. The game runs smoothly, except for that one bug with the Main Thread slowing down. I think it's because it updates the entire game upon destroying a block, perhaps easily fixable. Suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE: sorry for all the comments. but I fixed it. It's only laggy when its not maximized on play. It's odd, but whatever.

Comment: @Kayden Some games run better when running full-screen rather than in a window, maybe the same with yours.  NVIDIA Geforce Experience prompts me with all the games in my library.  Glad you got it going.  Well done

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thank you for your help. It is going well so far. It's only laggy when I don't have "Maximize on play" enabled. I can have millions of blocks and there's no lag whilst in fullscreen like that. I expect it to run better on a stand alone program, compiled and ready to be played.(but theres a long way to go :p) All I have to do now is make sure that 2 of the same dropped block item combines, so theres not hundreds of blocks sitting there, but only one!